# multiple repositories in the same folder

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository, bitbucket

I checked something out on github, can I commit that entire folder to bitbucket and be able to pull and push from both github and bitbucket? as well as have multiple and different branches between repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the target repo on bitbucket and then:

```
git remote add bitbucket <bitbucket-url>
```

Note that 'bitbucket' above is just an arbitrary name - use 'bb' or foo' if you like.

If you plan on working with both repos, I would also rename your 'origin' to something to remind you of true origin (e.g. 'github'):

```
git remote rename origin github
```

Check everything with:

```
git remote -v show

git remote show github

git remote show bitbucket
```

Read the man pages to see the longer form of [git push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) (along with the other commands like fetch, pull, etc.) to see how to push specific branches to specific repos, e.g.

```
git push bitbucket master

git push -u bitbucket master
```

I would also read up on the `remote` and `branch` sections of the [git config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) file.

Working with multiple repos is kind of "advanced" git - especially if you want to have distinct branches on each.  It would be very easy to accidentally push a branch (or a set of changes you intended to keep private) to the wrong repo, especially if you are new to git.  I don't know how negative the ramifications are of doing that would be for your situation.

Comment: great, so lets say it is a private repo on bitbucket, will the other participants that only have access to bitbucket repo need to know any special considerations?

Comment: @CMQ - None that I can think of at the moment.

Comment: out of curiousity, if a new user pulled the github repo (after I pushed changes) will they be able to see that there are multiple remotes? ("origin" and "something else")

Comment: @CQM - no, the new user wouldn't see anything about the other remotes; github itself wouldn't be aware (unless you set that up explicitly in github. Now one might guess about the other remotes if there are clues in the commit comments or branch/tag names on github.

Comment: in this example, would they github users see the usernames of the bitbucket users

Comment: Ah true, if those username/email address were from some reason affiliated with the other repo site.

Answer (score 1):

Note that BertF's answer creates several *branches* for separate remote repositories in the same local repository. What you probably need is separate *repositories*, one for each remote. Mixing up separate lines of development isn't a good idea, and as git is very lightweigt, having separate repositories (perhaps in a directory to keep them nearby) is easier to handle, and doesn't use much more resources.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the op asked for: "be able to pull and push from both github and bitbucket"?